# What makes barrel connectors good at carrying high power?

Tags: power, connector, power-connector

[The USB-PD standard is being updated to support 240W outputs](https://www.anandtech.com/show/16712/usbc-power-delivery-hits-240w-with-extended-power-range), and I've been seeing a lot of talk about how the USB-C connector will probably have problems carrying the very high voltage (5 amps @ 48V is being proposed). We've been using barrel connectors to power beefy PCs that require 240W or even more for a long time, what makes them better at carrying high power over a USB-C cable?

Comment: Contact surface area would be a major contributor to higher currents. Voltages is one of insulation.

Comment: Connection resistance define max current.

Comment: Tip: connectors don't carry wattages - they carry current. They don't care what the voltage is (and hence what the power is) except if you make or break connection while load is connected (but that's what switches are for and why they have fast toggle-action).

Comment: @Transistor It is true that they don't carry wattages but they absolutely do care about voltage. That's why high voltage connectors such as 230 V plugs have such big spacing  (creepage) compared to e.g. USB connectors.

Comment: @fishlein, agreed, but that's for a different reason than the "wattage" which is the topic here (contact rating rather than insulation rating).

Answer (score 15):

Current is all about contact surface area. For example this random high current barrel connector from the internet has plenty of metal fingers on both electrodes to make a solid contact.

[image]

Cheaper ones often have just one metal finger on the ground, and one or two tiny springs in the other connector to make contact with the tip.

Because everything has to be thin, now laptops use flat barrel connectors too:

[image]

Same story, it has chunky spring contacts. A large spring contact has more area and can apply a lot more pressure than a tiny USB-C contact.

However... USB-C connectors are rated for 5A, there are 4 power pins, so that's only 1.25A per pin. So it's not that bad.

Personally I'm not fond of using these at high currents. If one of the power pins breaks or has a bad contact, or a wire to one of the power pins breaks in the cable, current will have to go through the remaining ones, which makes dissipation a lot higher. Molex [rates](https://www.mouser.fr/datasheet/2/276/2/2130830005_IO_CONNECTORS-1953513.pdf) some of theirs at 5A per contact but doesn't spec contact resistance, Amphenol says [40mOhm](https://www.mouser.fr/datasheet/2/18/1/io_waterproof_usb_type_c-1524527.pdf) per contact, at 5A that would burn a watt on contact resistance so that's not really convincing.

It can probably work, but I wouldn't trust it to be as reliable as a barrel connector, round or flat. Googling "melted USB-C connector" gives 6 million results.

Now as far as voltage is concerned, the above datasheet mention 100V which I have trouble believing, some mention 30V which looks more realistic, so who knows. I wonder what the test conditions are (probably "squeaky clean") and what the insulation voltage of a USB-C connector will be in real conditions with a bit of crud, pocket lint, sweat or moisture...

In addition there are high speed data lines right next to the power lines, so a short between these would probably blow some hard to replace chips on the motherboard. Thunderbolt has the same issue. I've seen a video from Rossman where that happened and the Thunderbolt chip had fried to the point of burning a hole through the PCB itself.

Barrel connectors have fewer opportunities for disaster...

Answer (score 6):

Any connection (connector or switch) has a "contact resistance" associated with it. The current passing through any resistance, including "contact resistance" create a voltage drop across that resistance.  Two issues with this...

1. This voltage drop across the contact resistance decreases the voltage supplied to the device down stream of the connector.
2. the voltage drop, multiplied by the current passing through the resistance is the heat (in watts) generated at the contact.  That HEAT must be dissipated into the connector, the connector Housing and the cable should all be used to keep the TEMPERATURE within operating targets. If heat cannot be dissipated, the contacts can keep heating, which increases contact resistance and creates a positive feedback scenario to create even more heating until you damage the connector with a catastrophic thermal breakdown at the connection.

Higher surface contact creates better connections.  The barrel connector is physically larger (to dissipate heat) and larger wires can be connected to it (which can act as heat sinks by drawing heat away from the contact).  They're large size also means you can run fat traces to them when you use PCB mounted barrel connectors. A USB-C connector is pretty congested with many connections and limited to two power pins and two ground pins (plus grounded case mounting pins) to the PCB that are all generally 0.7mm pads at best.

Finally, one problem with barrel connectors is that they are round and it is difficult to make good connections to round surfaces. Flat (rectangular) versions have been designed but typically custom sized like a Lenovo laptop connector. Innovation will continue - I am sure.

Answer (score 3):

For truly high power, the CCTV industry modified the coaxial barrel power connector to carry even more current:

1. Split pin on the male (like a banana) to impart more pressure into the socket
2. Thicker metal shell
3. The female's shell reaches around the front, making it look like an RCA/Phono jack

Some pictures [from my site](http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?st=1&nm=by_names&bm=by_compon&c=round_conn&u=concentric_conn&o=barrel_power_conn&f=cctv_power_barrel_conn) may help.
[image]

Note that the gender is opposite from the standard coaxial barrel power connector: the plug is a male, and the jack is a female.

Comment: It would be better if you edited the question.

Comment: Good point. Done. Thanks.